# StreamCorruptedException in JRE7

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I have a private.key file in my application.

When I try to read the key in IBMJDK5 with below code it's working fine :

```
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(VropsEncrypt.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE));          

        Object readObject = objectInputStream.readObject();

        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) readObject;
```

But when I switched to jre7 the same code is throwing StreamCorruptedException at "objectInputStream.readObject();"

Comment: Presumably it doesn't like the data streamed from your `VropsEncrypt` reference. Are your libraries referenced correctly for that class to register correctly in JDK7?

Comment: VropsEncrypt.PRIVATE_KEY_FILE is the file location in my code base